# How to create a file with a single line?

Tags: ansible

The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_files_modules.html) for file operations does not seem to mention a module which would allow me to create a file with **one** line. The closest is [`lineinfile`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html) but this module also inserts markers (so a minimum of three lines).

The line will be generated from variables so I do not want to use a local file transferred to the target.

Is there such a module? Or should I run a shell command such as

```
command: echo {{ myvariable }} > the_file_to_create
```

to generate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily with `copy` module using `force=no` to create a new empty file only when the file does not yet exist (if the file exists, it's content is preserved)

```
- name: Copy the content 
  copy:
    content: "{{ myvariable }}"
    dest: /location/of/the/file
    force: no
```

Hope that might help you.

Comment: Thank you  - I missed the fact that `content` can be just a line (I mismatched that with `src`)