# setting value in cgroup's cpu.rt_runtime_us with ansible

Tags: ansible, redhat

I am setting a value on `cpu.rt_runtime_us` with *echo* command, like:

```
echo 950000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/user.slice/cpu.rt_runtime_us
```

It is on Redhat OS.

Is there more elegant way to configure it?

I'd like to use it in an ansible playook and I don't like using `shell` task and run this command every time playbook is run.

Appreciate any good proposal or a good practice for this kind of setting from ansible.

Comment: `copy` is probably want you want. See this: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ansible-create-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file with a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653018/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-single-line)